# Getting list of all projects or batches with MTurk API

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am creating an application where I need to
 1. Fetch the list of projects/batches currently a requester has in his account.
 2. Based on the batch/project ID I need to fetch all HITs under that batch.

Is there any MTurk API to do this task ?
I was going through this [MTurk API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetReviewableHITsOperation.html) but did not get any such API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not support batches. Those should be considered features specific to the Requester User Interface (RUI) (i.e., the web interface).

HITs from a batch have a `RequesterAnnotation` value of something like "BatchID:123456;". This can be used to identify HITs via API operations, but there are no operations that automatically work on a batch.